# Firebase And Trigger.io User Auth/Login

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, firebase

So I have already have a trigger.io hybrid app with functioning facebook authorization for android and iOS:

```
fbLogin: function() {
    forge.facebook.authorize(function (success) {
        forge.facebook.api('me', function (data) {
            forge.logging.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

`success` is a JSON object with the `access_token` and `data` is the huge JSON object facebook sends me with all the user info in it.

My question is, having these two objects, how do I use firebase's facebook api to authorize and login a user? I want to be able to use firebase's sessions mainly so the user doesn't have to log in every time he leaves the app.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to inject that session into Firebase, but on the Trigger.io side: if you quit the app and restart it, you shouldn't need to re-authenticate with Facebook. Sessions are cached in the FB SDK itself - are you not seeing that behaviour?

Comment: Okay I see that now, I don't need firebase sessions after all.